# Android vector drawable for launcher icon and other images on Android N

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, android-7.0-nougat

I'm going to use vector drawable feature for action bar icons and notification icon, on my app.

With the announce of **Android N**, one of his most important feature is **Screen Zoom** (on [Accessibility Improvements section](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#accessibility)). Another interesting feature is **Multi-window support** (see [link](http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#multi-window_support) if you want more info).

Does this means that we should use vector drawable also for launcher icon and other images used on app?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Vector drawable is not supported for launcher icons. You are, however, encouraged to use it everywhere else.

Comment: Is this still correct? I am able to use vector drawable like this: <application android:icon="@drawable/mysvg_logo"... I could even see in on the launcher.

Comment: If you're using automatic vector => PNG conversion, it will work fine. If you're only running on API 21+, it might work fine depending on your asset and the launcher being used; however, I don't think Play Store will allow you to upload an APK with a vector icon.

Comment: Contradicting that, I've not only found several apps using vector icons (XML) as launcher icon, but [this tutorial](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%202/51_c_drawables,_styles,_and_themes.html#creating-icons) even recommends it. So if there's any (official) source to either confirm or reject your statement, a link would be welcome.

Comment: @alanv This answer is useful and it deserves a mention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47910420/2013835

Comment: This answer is outdated

Comment: @Izzy can you update the tutrial link? it shows 404

Comment: That was six years ago… Maybe archive.org still has it? Unfortunately not, so I have no idea where to look, sorry @GeorgeShalvashvili

Answer (score 28):

You can use vector drawables as launcher icon if you follow these steps:

1. Place vector launcher icon under `drawable` directory. You can't place vector drawables in `mipmap` directory because they will work only in API levels 21 and above. As you possible know it's recommended to place PNG launcher icons under `mipmap-<density>` directories instead of `drawable-<density>` ones, and this matters because if you have a split apk build or use the new `aab` format to upload your app (["Google Dynamic Delivery"](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure)), both processes will remove all `drawable-<density>` directories except the one for the current density.
2. Remove `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in `build.gradle` `defaultConfig` section if you set it earlier. This will enable build-time PNG generation for vector drawables for API levels lower then 21. If you do not remove this option than `android:icon` attribute of the `<application>` tag will load default Android "green robot" icon.

I tested it on API level 16 device and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it in my next sprint. I'm just a little worried about compatibility, because I target 16 and 19 as min SDK in my projects.

Comment: @JJ86 I tested it on API level 16 device and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Comment: Is #2 still valid for Gradle v4+ and Support Library v26+? I would expect at least a compiler warning if you would got this robot icon on some systems...

Comment: This works as long as you don't use gradients (which require API 24).

Answer (score 4):

It seems vector drawables are now supported for launcher icons.
I have recently uploaded and published an [app](https://github.com/code-schreiber/QuickCode/tree/develop) (to alpha) with a vector drawable as a laucher icon.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities