# making a smooth looking app launcher icon

Tags: android, drawable, android-4.4-kitkat, android-launcher

First of all, 
[Blurry Launcher Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371884/blurry-launcher-icons)  is a bit different from what I'm asking.

I designed a logo for a test app but it doesn't seem to get smooth at all. Compare google play's logos and my custom logo:
[image]

It has very jagged edges and I don't know how to fix it. I have provided three different dimensions for the `mipmap-mdpi`, `mipmap-hdpi`, `mipmap-xhdpi` and `mipmap-xxhdpi` with `512 X 512 px`, `1024 X 1024 px` , `2046 X 2046 px` and `4096 X 4096 px` respectively yet it just keeps rendering this sort of look. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912428/android-vector-drawable-for-launcher-icon-and-other-images-on-android-n) that `vector drawables` are not supported for launcher icons so I don't know what the solution is and why is it rendering this way.  Here is a [temporary link to the .svg file used](https://easyupload.io/g6afef)

P.S: I'm looking for kitkate and above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make a vector for sure. That SO answer was from 2016.

Comment: @Blundell , how do you use vector? we don't have app:srcCompat in the manifest right?

Comment: use this tool "Create adaptive and legacy launcher icons": https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio

Comment: @Blundell, This semms to do work to some extent, but it's impossible to get a transparent backgrond using this tool. It says to choose a foreground and background layer and then creates a grey layer if a transparent image is fed, and provides no option for alpha = 0 if we select color. Do you know any workarounds?

Comment: Moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this tool "Create adaptive and legacy launcher icons":

[developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio)

[image]

I used this image for the background: https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/retrowave-sun-with-alpha-background-vaporwave-png-27.png it has alpha and the alpha is respected.

Comment: for the legacy icons, the background is greyish?